# How can I compare a number against a range in bash or Perl?

Tags: perl, bash, range

How to script a comparison of a number against a range?

> 1 is not within 2-5

or

> 3 is within 2-5

Answer (score 19):

#### It's even better in `Perl6`.

Chained comparison operators:

```
if( 2 <= $x <= 5 ){
}
```

Smart-match operator:

```
if( $x ~~ 2..5 ){
}
```

Junctions:

```
if( $x ~~ any 2..5 ){
}
```

Given / When operators:

```
given( $x ){
  when 2..5 {
  }
  when 6..10 {
  }
  default{
  }
}
```

Comment: So much of Perl 6 looks awesome that I think I can forgive the few things that don't.

Comment: Given/When also works in 5.10, it's one of the things that was back-ported to Perl5.

Comment: Truly, when Perl 6 arrives it will change the way your grandchildren write code.

Comment: Since the task can be solved without difficulty in existing Perls, it makes me cringe to see that this answer -- which lists a pile of incredibly marginal improvements from a language that doesn't exist yet -- should be at the top. I'm tempted to -1 this just to reduce the cringe factor.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: "doesn't exist yet" is out of date FUD.  you could say "not yet released", but it sure does exist: http://www.perl.com/download.csp#perl6

Comment: They only seem to be "marginal improvements" because this is a trivial example. Junctions are amazing...

Comment: @jettero: To be clear, I'm not saying that the features themselves are marginal, only that using them to solve this particular problem is.

Comment: @ysth: Thanks for the pointer. It looks like Perl 6 is further along than I thought. But a look at the Rakudo feature status page: http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl6/index.cgi?rakudo_feature_status tells me things aren't stable enough yet for anything but playing.

Comment: I didn't intend for this to get more up-votes than any other question, I just wanted to spread the word about Perl6.

Comment: It has been 13 years since we started this discussion, and Perl 6 hasn't been released yet. I guess @j_random_hacker was right when he said it "doesn't exist yet".

Comment: @FernandoSilveira What are you talking about? Perl6 was released in 2015. It then had a name change to Raku in 2019. There are also people who are currently using it in production. I've even had a person offer to pay me for Raku code that I had written.

Comment: So that's why I don't find Perl 6 releases on Perl's official website. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: All of the provided examples are experimental, since 2009.

Comment: Chained comparison operators are now supported in Perl 5.32.

Answer (score 13):

In Perl:

```
if( $x >= lower_limit && $x <= upper_limit ) {
   # $x is in the range
}
else {
   # $x is not in the range
}
```

Comment: appreciate the quick replies!

Comment: Um ... I think some sigils are missing. Perl probably does the right thing but you might also want to keep in mind that perl uses floating point as default for numbers, so you have the potential for the 0.999999... == 1.0 problem. But I'm an old Fortran programmer, so discount my words accordingly.

Comment: Recent perls try hard to keep integers stored as such.

Comment: thanks for the edits brian. The invisible $ in perl frequently bites me.

Comment: I prefer if( lower_limit <= $x && $x <= upper_limit ).

Comment: @ysth, I believe that if you had "$x = 5;" perl should keep it as an integer if possible, but if you had "$x = (1 / 2) * 10;" I would hope it would be kept as a float. Unless the problem domain is specifically restricted to integers, the floating point issue merits at least a consideration.

Comment: I almost want to mark this as Perl5, instead of Perl, but it works on Perl6 as well.

Answer (score 11):

In bash:

```
$ if [[ 1 -gt 2 && 1 -lt 5 ]]; then echo "true"; fi
$ if [[ 3 -gt 2 && 1 -lt 5 ]]; then echo "true"; fi
true
```

Comment: Just for fun:  if seq $lo $hi | grep -w $num; then echo yes indeedy sir; fi

Comment: if (( lower <= x && x <= upper )); then echo true; fi

Answer (score 10):

The [smart match operator](http://perl5maven.com/smart-matching-in-perl-5.10) is available in Perl 5.10, too:

```
if ( $x ~~ [2..5] ) {
    # do something
}
```

Comment: yeah, and 

any {$_ == $x} 2..5

can be done using List::MoreUtils

Comment: or Quantum::Superpositions.  but that or L::MU's any are so horrifically expensive that it curdles my prematurely optimizing blood to think of using them for trivial tests.

Answer (score 2):

In Bash:

```
x=9; p="\<$x\>"; if [[ $(echo {10..20}) =~ $p ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

Edited to correctly handle conditions as noted in the comment below.

```
rangecheck () { local p="\<$1\>"; if [[ $(echo {10..20}) =~ $p ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi; }
for x in {9..21}; do rangecheck "$x"; done
false
true
.
.
.
true
false
```

Comment: Fails as `if [[ $(echo {10..20}) =~ 9 ]]; then echo true; fi` returns true. Good idea though, could be improved? (I lack much bash knowledge)

Comment: @ShrikantSharat: I have edited my answer to correct that problem. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

In perl

```
grep {/^$number$/} (1..25);
```

will give you a true value if the number is in the range and a false value otherwise.

For example:

```
[dsm@localhost:~]$ perl -le 'print "has `$ARGV[0]`" if grep {/^$ARGV[0]$/} (1..25)' 4
has `4`
[dsm@localhost:~]$ perl -le 'print "has `$ARGV[0]`" if grep {/^$ARGV[0]$/} (1..25)' 456
[dsm@localhost:~]$
```

Comment: "will give you a non-empty list" - actually, perl will return true/false when grep is used in scalar context (like in your examples) - and newer perls also short circuit in this case, iirc.

Answer (score 1):

The `[[` version of test has supported regular expressions since Bash 3.0.

```
[[ 3 =~ ^[2-5]$ ]]; echo $? # 0
```

The numeric comparison operators in test sometimes return an error if the input isn't numeric:

```
[[ 1a -ge 1 ]]; echo $? # value too great for base (error token is "1a")
[[ '$0' -le 24 ]] # syntax error: operand expected (error token is "$o")
```

You can test if the input is an integer with `=~`:

```
x=a23; [[ "$x" =~ ^[0-9]+$ && "$x" -ge 1 && "$x" -le 24 ]]; echo $? # 1
x=-23; [[ "$x" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ && "$x" -ge -100 && "$x" -le -20 ]]; echo $? # 0
```