# perl - How to check a value to be present in specific range?

Tags: regex, perl

Is it possible to compare the value of an expression like this in perl?

```
if(0x100 < $my_var < 0x200) {
    return $my_var;
}
```

The above way gives a syntax error.

In perl, Is there a better way to check if the value is present in specific range?

I don't want to use two if conditions to do this. I am sure,for this, there would a better way in any language.

Sorry if this a very basic question. I am trying to write my first programs in perl.

**Edit**

```
if($my_var >0x100  && $my_var < 0x200)
```

I donot like the above method. Please let me know if there is any other sophisticated way. I would be using it a lot on 64 bit addresses. Hence writing like this, would make the code look ugly. Please suggest other ways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597497/how-can-i-compare-a-number-against-a-range-in-bash-or-perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597497/how-can-i-compare-a-number-against-a-range-in-bash-or-perl)

Comment: @jkshah unfortunately some of high rated answers make use of smart match which is deprecated.

Comment: @mpapec I see. documentation is very detailed! Anyway I like simple writing and I don't understand why OP wants to complicate the things by calling simple and elegant `if($my_var >0x100  && $my_var < 0x200) ` syntax as **ugly**!

Comment: @Manty: It would help us to help you if you explained why you don't like `if ($my_var > 0x100  && $my_var < 0x200)`. That would be the standard way to do this in Perl.

Comment: @jkshah I said i dont like it because i thought there would be a better way where i can write the variable name just once(like in C). If this is the standatd in perl i will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own function,

```
sub between {
  my ($x,$y,$z) = @_;

  return ($x < $y and $y < $z);
}

if (between(0x100, $my_var, 0x200)) { print "OK"; }
```

Comment: Very sorry. I didn't get the explanation. Probably because i am very new to pearl. If possible, elaborate a little bit else I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this itself coz it dont not take much effort if there are two conditions inside an if:

```
if($my_var >0x100  && $my_var < 0x200)
```

`if($x ~~ 0X100..0X200)` will also work **but in perl6 not in perl5**

If you are not using perl6 then forget about the above method.

Comment: Hi VIjay. Any other ways?

Answer (score 2):

You need to break the conditional up in to two separate tests along with an and statement, 
like so,

```
# This example should print "Pass"
my $my_var = 0x150;
if (0x100 < $my_var && $my_var < 0x200) {
  print "Pass\n";
} else {
  print "Fail\n";
}
```

This is the most common way of dealing with ranges. For something a bit different that might still prove useful, you an use the [smart match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) (aka. [inchworm operator](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/secret-perl-operators/#inchworm))<sup>1</sup> along with the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) which might actually prove more readable when dealing with memory spaces,

```
# This example should show that 0x150 and 0x190 pass
my @addresses = (0x090, 0x150, 0x190, 0x210);
for my $address (@addresses) {
  if ($address ~~ [0x100 .. 0x200]) {
    print "$address - Pass\n";
  } else {
    print "$address - Fail\n";
  }
}
```

---

1. Note that smart match is experimental / depercated depending upon which version of Perl you are using. [match::smart](https://metacpan.org/pod/match%3a%3asmart) provides the same functionality.

Comment: +1 for the first part, but `~~` is only an *inchworm* pseudooperator as a prefix operator. Used like here as a binary infix operator, it is the [*smartmatch operator*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator). Smartmatch was introduced in 5.10 when people were drunk on the new ideas from Perl6. Now that we have sobered up, it's considered to have been a mistake. The current release of perl has actually marked smartmatch as experimental, with the intent to re-design it in the future. Because this will likely be backwards-incompatible, everyone should now stop using smartmatch.

Comment: @amon Interesting, I've updated the answer to note the match::smart package since it should work the same in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would just assign upper and lower values to variables `$high` `$low` and do:

```
if($val > $low && $val < $high)
```