# Using sed command to replace an interval of natural numbers

Tags: sed

How can you use the **sed** command to **replace** all **numbers** **between 24 and 88** or **between 224 and 239** with the text "[Number X is not available]". The numbers are in a text file mixed with other numbers between 0 and 500 and other characters.

Note that if the text has for example the string "124" sed must not replace it by "1[Number 24 is not available]" but x24w must be replaced by "x[Number 24 is not available]w"

Comment: Don't. Use a better tool like `awk`.

Comment: See [this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36959/80273) for why it's recommended not to use sed. It's an example of adding two numbers, and it requires 22 lines of really convoluted code because you have to start by implementing the concept of a number.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Also please do let us know why `24` is getting considered for `124`? Shouldn't it be considered as `124` itself? Kindly clarify on this one too in your question.

Answer (score 0):

sed is not the right tool. i would use perl. Here is a snippet for replacing numbers between 11 and 14:

generate some test data :

```
seq 10 15 | xargs -I N echo  abcNdef12x123yz 
abc10def12x123yz
abc11def12x123yz
abc12def12x123yz
abc13def12x123yz
abc14def12x123yz
abc15def12x123yz
```

now replace it with perl:

```
seq 10 15 | xargs -I N echo  abcNdef12x123yz | perl -ne 's/(\d+)/( ($1>10 && $1<15) ? "[Number $1 is not available]" : $1 )/ge;print'
abc10def[Number 12 is not available]x123yz
abc[Number 11 is not available]def[Number 12 is not available]x123yz
abc[Number 12 is not available]def[Number 12 is not available]x123yz
abc[Number 13 is not available]def[Number 12 is not available]x123yz
abc[Number 14 is not available]def[Number 12 is not available]x123yz
abc15def[Number 12 is not available]x123yz
```

explanation

- `perl -ne` loops through every input line
- `s/(\d+)//eg` replaces each number in the line with the result of an executed perl statement
- `($1>10 && $1<15) ? "[Number $1 is not available]" : $1` this is the short form for an if-then-else (the ternary conditional operator). if $1 (the matched number) is in the range, it will be replaced, otherwise it will be replaced by itself (no changes).

you can run that twice for your special ranges, or change the condition to:

`( $1 >= 24 && $1 <= 88 ) || ( $1 >= 224 && $1 <= 239 )`

so the complete solution is:

```
cat your_file | perl -ne 's/(\d+)/( ( $1 >= 24 && $1 <= 88 ) || ( $1 >= 224 && $1 <= 239 ) ? "[Number $1 is not available]" : $1 )/ge;print' > your_new_file
```

Comment: Why `perl -ne '...;print'` and not `perl -pe '...'`?

Comment: [Also, there are slicker ways of doing ranges in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597497/how-can-i-compare-a-number-against-a-range-in-bash-or-perl), up to and including the `~~` smartmatch operator.  I favor this: `grep /$1/,(24..88,224..239) ? :` just because I find it readible.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Do you know if the grep could be a little bit slower, because it does much more compare operations?

Comment: Correct-- grep will be insanely slow relative to your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+/\n&\n/g;s/\<(2[4-9]|[3-7][0-9]|8[0-8]|22[4-9]|23[0-9])\>/[Number & is not available]/g;s/\n//g' file
```

This matches numbers 24-29, 30-79, 80-88, 224-229 and 230-239.